# Using recursion, is it possible to set the initial input as a fixed letter so that it will not be affected as the process loops?

Tags: python

Implement the function tree that takes a number of slices n and a rune as arguments, and generates a stack of runes (shape) scaled and overlayed on top of each other.

the shape at the top must be 1/n the size of the original shape. the shape at the second level must be 2/n the size of the original shape and so on. i.e. the shape at the bottom is the original shape.

So I tried to do this in a recursive manner using some ideas from mathematical induction.

```
def tree(n, shape):
    a = n
    if n == 1:
        return scale(1/a, shape)
    else:
        return overlay_frac((n-1)/n, tree(n-1, shape) , scale(n/a, shape))
```

My question is how would you fix the initial value of `n` because this recursion keeps altering the value? I can't set `a = n` outside of the recursion as `n` is defined in the function.

Is there a way for me to set the initial value of `n` to another letter so it wouldn't change?

Right now I'm not even sure if this code works. But without being able to fix it, I can't test it.

FYI: I am aware that you guys might not know what `overlay_frac` and `scale` does but the codes for those are given to me.

My question really revolves around a way to set the initial input of a recursion so that it will not be affected as the process loops.

Comment: Why the `numpy` tag?  What's the purpose of the `a=n` assignment?  With that you are just calling `scale` with either `1/n` or `1`.  It looks like `n` is just a number, and within `tree` both `n` and `a` are local variables.

Comment: @hpaulj i'm not sure about the numpy tag, i don't know what that is. the problem is that the second recursion `tree(n-1, shape)` needs to be based on the initial n instead of n-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is add a third parameter that will keep track of the original size, and have your arguments in your `overlay_frac()` function be based off of that variable, so that the values don't alter in recursion. Here's how I've done it:

```
def tree(n, initial_size, shape):
    a = initial_size
    if n == 1:
        return scale(1/a, shape)
    else:
        return overlay_frac((n-1)/a, tree(n-1, initial_size, shape), \
                            scale(n/a, shape))
```

Comment: thanks man! that certain guarantees that i'm looking in the right direction - i tested it and it worked. but the problem is that the question requires the function `tree` to only take in the 2 inputs.

But thanks man! I managed to figure it out by redefining `tree` as `tree_prelude` then `def tree(n, shape): return tree_prelude(n,shape,n)`.

Comment: No problem! You could make `tree_prelude` be the inner function of `tree` so that it can only be used by that function.

Answer (score 1):

Adding another parameter is certainly a feasible option. In the event that you under certain constraints and unable to change the formal parameters defined for the outer function, you may consider using a helper function as well.

```
function tree(n, rune){
    function drawTree(i) {
        if (i === 1) {
            return rune;
        } else {
            return overlay_frac(1 / k, scale((1 + n - i)/ n, rune),
                drawTree(i - 1));
        }
    }
    return drawTree(n);
}
```